# Is that Possible to connect database except sports2000 in AppBuilder?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is that Possible to connect database except sports2000 in AppBuilder?  the database will be same as sports 2000 which i planning to connect.

Comment: What is your problem? Are you getting an error message? Which?

Comment: Actually some of the data stored in databases which is only can access through server.so i have a plan for take the database base backup .db and connect with app builder in database connections .if so i don't want to go to server and collect the data every time.

Comment: I'm not sure you necessarily want to connect your backup... If anything, creating a distinct staging database might be appropriate, but it sounds like you have a problem which may require a more thought out solution. Feel free to post that question!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect multiple databases. But you need to use distinct logical database names. That is the -ld parameter on the connection.